# Should these two tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have a [law](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) tag and a [copyright](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) tag, currently the law tag is being used to ask about content copyright, and the same is the case with the other tag, to me both don't need to be on here and one of them should atleast be merged into the other.

Should they be merged? if so should we keep a general tag like [law](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law), or a more specific tag like [copyright](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright)?

Comment: Can we please include the names of the tags in the title? It makes it a lot more helpful when browsing around on Meta.

Answer (score 4):

It really comes down to a question of if there are sufficient copyright related questions to justify the tag's existence. (I have a feeling there may not be.)  While I can think of a lot of law related questions, the number of questions about copyright is far more limited.  If we get rid of it, we will certainly need to keep law.  There is no way the two are synonyms and law is the most inclusive.

Copyright also is interesting in that it could have some ambiguity.  It could deal with both the legal side of legal obligations towards removing copyright content, but it could also deal with the licenses and copyright of content that is posted in a community as well.  This later category might not fit quite so well in to the law tag.

I guess my initial impression would be to keep both for now unless copyright ends up being underutilized.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking keeping a more general tag is going to be the better option in this case, so that we don't get too many tags too quickly. This is also good if the law related question is unlikely to have many other similar questions.

Though, since law is a very broad topic, keeping sub-groups of these tags may be good for instances where we get many questions related to the topic.